# How to remove white space for string " $ … 123.56 " in javascript

Tags: javascript, replace, trim

i have getting my input as `$                                                …                                          123.56`. How to change it has "$ 123.56" in javascript

Comment: Does your string actually have the `...` at the beginning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're looking for this?

```
var priceInput = " $ … 123.56 ";
var priceOutput = priceInput.replace('… ', '');
```